# Matching 2 DF's by 2 columns R

Tags: r

If I have 2 DF's with the same values in, but in different orders can I create a 3rd DF with values of the 2nd DF matching the first?

Ex:

```
HomeTeam <- c("Liverpool", "Southampton", "Arsenal", "Everton", "Chelsea")
AwayTeam <- c("Burnley", "Brighton", "Man United", "Tottenham", "Man City")

df1 <- tibble(HomeTeam, AwayTeam)

HomeTeam <- c("Southampton", "Arsenal", "Chelsea", "Liverpool", "Everton")
AwayTeam <- c("Brighton", "Man United", "Man City", "Burnley", "Tottenham")


df2 <- tibble(HomeTeam, AwayTeam)


HomeTeam <- c("Liverpool", "Southampton", "Arsenal", "Everton", "Chelsea")
AwayTeam <- c("Burnley", "Brighton", "Man United", "Tottenham", "Man City")

df3 <- tibble(HomeTeam, AwayTeam)
```

Both DF's consist of thousands of rows of data, yet out of order. 
Thanks.

Comment: the 'df3' looks same as 'df1'.  So, in that case, wouldn't just `df2 <- df1`

Comment: Do you need `df2 %>% arrange(match(HomeTeam, df1$HomeTeam), match(AwayTeam, df1$AwayTeam))`

Comment: @Akrun - thanks, I'll try that. There's a couple more columns in both DF's (they have different names though) I'll see if I can match it all up though. I'll edit my opening post if I need extra help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `match` to get the index for `arrange`ing the rows

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
    arrange(match(HomeTeam, df1$HomeTeam), match(AwayTeam, df1$AwayTeam))
```

---

Also, if there are more columns, it may be better to `paste` those columns and do a single `match`

```
library(stringr)
df2 %>%
     arrange(match(str_c(HomeTeam, AwayTeam), str_c(df1$HomeTeam, df1$AwayTeam)))
```

NOTE: For big datasets, `match` would be potentially faster than a join as we are extracting a single column or vector from the other dataset to be used in the `match`

---

Or another option is `data.table` join which would be fast as well

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[setDT(df1), on = .(HomeTeam, AwayTeam)]
#     HomeTeam   AwayTeam
#1:   Liverpool    Burnley
#2: Southampton   Brighton
#3:     Arsenal Man United
#4:     Everton  Tottenham
#5:     Chelsea   Man City
```

Comment: Again, thank you so much. The 2nd option has worked beautifully.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, so appologies for whoever has downvoted you. I upvoted, again, thanks this has helped me with wrangle my data tenfold.

Comment: @ScoutingForJay it was not directed at you.  It's okay. thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can `left_join`/`inner_join` `df1` with `df2` to get `df2` data in same order as `df1`.

```
dplyr::left_join(df1, df2, by = c("HomeTeam", "AwayTeam"))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  HomeTeam    AwayTeam  
#  <chr>       <chr>     
#1 Liverpool   Burnley   
#2 Southampton Brighton  
#3 Arsenal     Man United
#4 Everton     Tottenham 
#5 Chelsea     Man City
```